# Not able to mount D-Link DMW-156 on ubuntu system

Tags: networking, usb, linux, ubuntu, internet

D-Link DMW-156 is a 3g USB dongle, when I plugin to the usb it shows green light for few seconds and then red light.Have tried the following commands on the terminal.

```
sudo mount /dev/sr1/mnt
mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sr1 does not exist.

sudo mount /dev/sr0/mnt
mount: /mnt: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

Thanks for the help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8YBd.png

Comment: AFAIK, the debian package on the modem itself is x86 and will therefore not work on the Pi. Best option is probably to check `sakis3g`.

Comment: erm, you don't "mount" network adapters

Comment: try `dmesg` ... see if there's any errors/messages regarding that adapter

Comment: @dmesg  ..no errors..have attached the screenshot please check out.